# Why the mInflater in ResourceCursorAdapter is private (instead of protected)?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

The `ResourceCursorAdapter` derives from `CursorAdapter` and adds also the `mInflater` (initialized in constructors). I have seen more than one custom adapter examples derived from `SimpleCursorAdapter` (that in turn is based on `ResourceCursorAdapter`) that also introduced their own `myInflater` for the same purpose.

Is there any reason why the `mInflater` was not made `protected` instead of `private` so that it could be used also in derived classes?

**Update:** To clarify my question.

Firstly, I am just curious of *why the `mInflater` was not made protected*. What was the reason to do that during design as it would be quite handy when using `ResourceCursorAdapter` or its subclass `SimpleCursorAdapter` as a base class? I have finally implemented my cursor adapter by extending the `CursorAdapter`. Anyway, I am just curious, and I may have overlooked something important...

I want to use the `ViewHolder` technique. Because of that, I want to override the `newView` (it creates a view holder and attaches it to the newly created view) and `bindView` (it gets the attached view holder and fills the data from a cursor). For the `newView` method implementation, I need to call the inflater. If I were using the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, I would defined the `mInflater` initialized by my subclass constructor exactly the same way as the `ResourceCursorAdapter` does (to optimize slightly the `newView`). For that reason, it would be nice if the superclass `mInflater` was available also for subclasses (i.e. no need to define it again in the subclass). This is the core of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResourceCursorAdapter` is a special adapter that does the inflating for you. For this reason, subclasses of it should not need an inflater.

If you need to inflate a layout, then `ResourceCursorAdapter` is probably not the most appropriate choice.

Comment: Well, but any `CursorAdapter` based class defines `newView`, and if the view layout is based on resource XML, you would do exactly the same, and the optimization would be to create the `LayoutInflater` variable to avoid repetition of `mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`. Then why *"If you need to inflate a layout, then ResourceCursorAdapter is probably not the most appropriate choice"*? Or what do you recommend? (I am the Android beginner.)

Comment: i don't understand your question. if you have a layout xml file that you need to inflate for each view, use a resourceCursorAdapter, it does that for you, and you have no need for an inflater yourself

Comment: ResourceCursorAdapter is specifically made for people who are not overriding newView, and therefore do not need the inflater. You can use a ViewHolder with a ResourceCursorAdapter, you'll simply put it in the bindView, and you don't need to override the newView. (and you don't need an inflater)

Comment: OK. I probably understand now. Still, the `bindView` already gets the ViewHolder. The ViewHolder instance should be added earlier. And probably the best place where the ViewHolder is `setTag`ged to the view is the `newView()`. But the overriden `newView` can possibly call the `view = super.newView(...)` first (the inflation) and then create the holder and call the `view.setTag(holder)`.

Comment: agreed. you can override the newView and put your handler there.